# Query List returns Null when add toList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've tried to provide a simplified version of the problem I'm dealing with. Query 1 is enumerated and returns a `List` of `PersonViewModel`.

However, when I change the query and add a `.ToList()` before the select statement, query returns the value `null`.

The reason for this is because I want it enumerated first, so I can deal with the values in memory - in order to use functions such as `.toString` which cannot be converted to SQL.

Returns as expected

```
var query = (from s in context.PersonDetails.GetQueryable(x => x.Id == Id)
             select new PersonViewModel
             {
                 Name = s.Person.Firstname,
                 Number = s.Person.Number
             }).ToList();
```

Returns `null`

```
var query = (from s in context.PersonDetails.GetQueryable(x => x.Id == Id).toList()
             select new PersonViewModel
             {
                 Name = s.Person.Firstname,
                 Number = s.Person.Number
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: What exactly is `null` in your data?

Comment: `toList()` ... that's won't compile

Comment: The value of `query` certainly won't be `null`, unless the `ToList` method you're calling is an unusual one. It shouldn't contain any null references either, although it may contain `PersonViewModel` references with null values for `Name` and/or `Number` - is that what you meant?

Comment: It certainly shouldn't return null, as the top query does not. I assign model.Person = query, but model.Person returns null.

Comment: When you do it on database level, query engine will create join clause for you to retrieve ‘s.Person.*’. When you call ToList first system will retrieve flatten ‘s’ model without nested properties. What you can do is to add .Include(s=>s.Person) to your query

Comment: Assuming your `context` is an EntityFramework context and Lazy-Loading is turned off, it's obvious that if you're executing the query beforehand using `ToList()` your `Select()` would fail because `Person` isn't loaded. Only when your `Select()` is performed on an `IQueryable` can the query be translated to the proper SQL that will JOIN and include `Person`